# GWT: Retrieve generated classname

Tags: java, gwt

GWT: 2.7 with GSS

I would like to retrieve the parent (not the first one in the hierarchy) of an element using his classname.

To do this, I hoped to use the generated css classname from a CssResources but it doesn't give me the same classname as the one used in the DOM.

```
class Test
{
    interface Style extends CssResource
    {
        String test();
    }

    public interface Resource extends ClientBundle
    {
        @Source( "Test.gss" )
        Style style();
    }

    public static Resource res = GWT.create(Resource.class);
}
```

---

- Resource result `GWT.log(Test.res.style().test());`:

  [package-name]-[ClassName]-Style-test
- DOM result (MyRenderer is an UiRenderer where I used the style):

  [package-name]-[ClassName]_MyRendererImpl_GenCss_style-test

**What should I do to retrieve a specific parent of an element ?**
**Is there a best way to do it ?**

PS: I don't use Widget at all only Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole point (well, one of them) of `CssResource`: that the same class name in sources is turned into different ones once compiled, so you never fear name conflicts.

Generated names depend on the fully-qualified name of the `CssResource` interface, so you have to use the exact same interface (you can however use it in different `ClientBundle` interfaces, and that's actually a source of bugs: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144 )

Comment: Ok, it's clearer. I'm using my style in an `UiRenderer` like this  `<ui:style type="[package].[ClassName].Style" src="Test.gss" />`. I suppose that I have to pass the style in the `render` method of this `UiRenderer`. Right ?

Comment: Just use the same type (`[package].[ClassName].Style`) in a `ClientBundle`, with the same `Test.gss` source or a dummy one with empty CSS rules, it doesn't really matter, and use it like you showed in your question. And no need to change your `UiRenderer`, using the exact same `Style` interface should be enough.

Comment: I used this example to retrieve my style : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18560901/4395543 ,Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

if your element is already inside the Dom, try the Dom class to find the parent, see [reference](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html)
you have static methods to getElementbyId(String id) and getParent(Element element) which could help you here